# Using 11-36t 9 speed derailleur with 11-40t 9 speed cassette

Tags: derailleur, cassette, derailleur-rear

So I've got the [shimano altus rd-m2000](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/altus-m2000/RD-M2000.html) and it says that it only supports 11-36t. However, I've seen people on forums say that it's possible with this derailleur. Even it I was wondering if with a derailleur extender I'd be able to run a larger range, such as 11-40 or 11-42?

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47769/need-easier-gearing-what-would-the-effect-of-changing-the-chainring-or-cassette/47771#47771 and a few other answer may help. Summary is 'Can be done, but if it works, don't expect it to be great'